# Webpack Dev Server - hot reload on another local server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, websocket, webpack-dev-server

We have a React app that's embedded and served in .NET CMS project.
App is bootstrapped with Create React App and webpack config tweaked with craco.

Webpack dev server is running at default location http://localhost:3000 and CMS is running at https://localhost:5000

When I open https://localhost:5000, I correctly see React app. However, console is full of errors

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:3000/ws' failed:`

Is there a way to configure it to work with hot reload from external server?

I have tried setting dev server to https and adjusting webSocketURL, but did the error persists.